# Get user's timezone with PHP

Tags: php

Is there any way to get the timezone of the logged in user (or who is using an application) with PHP to save it in a variable?

Comment: You'll likely need to ask them, and store it in your database, since you can't depend on IP address to tell you where someone is located. How you do that is really up to you... As written, this is really too broad though: I suggest you edit to show specific code you've written, along with issues/errors you're running into. Also, please be careful with tags, to make sure they are specific to your question. I removed all but `php`, as they really didn't apply here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine a user's timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determine-a-users-timezone) You need to get it in JS and pass it to PHP.